# Pubnub Lua (Corona) Library not working

Tags: lua, coronasdk, pubnub

I am developing with Corona SDK, the most recent public release (v3.0, build 2015.2646), on OS X 10.10.

I have downloaded the pubnub corona repo from here: https://github.com/pubnub/lua/

When I try to run the pubnub examples, multiple examples are failing with a run-time error in the core pubnub.lua library.

For instance, example-channel-information, example-mathmania, example-multi-drum.

They all result in a console runtime error of:

```
Oct 20 10:46:51.328: Runtime error
.../pubnub/corona/examples/example-channel-information/pubnub.lua:534: attempt to call upvalue 'callback' (a table value)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'callback'
        .../pubnub/corona/examples/example-channel-information/pubnub.lua:534: in function <.../pubnub/corona/examples/example-channel-information/pubnub.lua:532>
        (tail call): ?
```

Is this a problem with my environment, or is there a more recent pubnub.lua release, or is this a bug?

thanks

Comment: If you haven't made any changes to the library and/or examples, I suggest you contact library creators directly.

Comment: thanks @bartek - pubnub site indicates that all support questions should be posted here on SO

Comment: @randog - where do you see that? SO is an alternate to support@pubnub.com - either way, we'll answer you question as we monitor SO closely for PubNub q's.

Comment: Can you provide sample app that reproduces this. If so, submit to support@pubnub.com and reference this SO link, too and we'll post back here with final answers.